# Database normalization of tables with only id and Description

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

Suppose I have two tables:

```
Table Genres: (Id, Description)
Table CD: (Id, ...CD related fields..., genreId)
```

If i eliminate my Genres table, and create my CD table like:

```
Table CD: (Id, ...CD related fields..., genreDescription)
```

and supposing my `CD<->Genre` relation is One To One will my table still be normalized?

My question is, when my table is only Id and Description, do i really need another table ?

Comment: Yes, it's normalized according to your model, but your model is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that genreDescription and all the other attributes of CD are determined only by the superkeys of that table and assuming that the presence of genreDescription in CD doesn't introduce any non-key functional dependencies into that table then we can say that CD satisfies at least Boyce-Codd Normal Form. Replacing genreDescription with a different attribute, genreId, wouldn't make the table any "more normalized" than it already is.

You may still want a Genre table as a convenient place to maintain the set of genres. The Genre table would be the place for any genre-determined attributes.

In choosing the right identification scheme for genres (and therefore a key for your Genre table) keep in mind the principles of Simplicity, Familiarity and Stability. Those are usually the desirable characteristics that make identifiers practical and usable. You need to decide whether genreDescription is a suitably simple, familiar and stable way to identify genres.